# Reach properties and methods in different namespaces from a callback function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the chartjs-plugin-annotation and need to fire an event when the user clicks on one annotation to render a tooltip text. According to the documentation, the plugin provides an event handler for the click event so I can get the clicked element:

```
      onClick: function(e) {
        let identifier = this.id; // identifier holds the reference to the clicked element in dom 
      }
```

But what I need is to pass this variable to a method in different namespace ( Window ). So I can use the following to reach the method:

```
      onClick: (e) => {
        this.functionToBeCalled(e);
        return;
      }
```

The issue is in the first script, "this" relates to the callback function, but in the second script, I can reach the function but don't have the reference to the element I want to pass to.

how can I fixe this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pass this variable to a method declare variable that to be reference to the method then use it inside onClick event

```
let that = this;

 onClick: function(e) {
 that.functionToBeCalled(e);
 return;
 }
```